# Can't solve this for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, graph

So I'm a beginner and I need to write a code that prints a x-y graph.
Here is my code:

```
dimx = int(input('lengte van de x-as: '))
dimy = int(input('lengte van de y-as: '))
b = int(input('b: '))
print("^")
for x in range(dimy):
    print("|")
    if x == b+1:
        for x in range(dimx):
            print("-",end="")
print("+"+"-"*dimx + ">")
```

The problem I have is my output prints out in the wrong order:

```
^
|
|
|
|
|
|
------------------------------|
|
|
|
+------------------------------>
```

What I need is:

```
^
|
|
|
|
|
|
|------------------------------
|
|
|
+------------------------------>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `print("|")` which without `end = ""` will print a new line afterwards unconditionally
You can instead print the newline at the end using an empty `print()`

```py
dimx = int(input('lengte van de x-as: '))
dimy = int(input('lengte van de y-as: '))
b = int(input('b: '))
print("^")
for x in range(dimy):
    print("|",end="") # print without newline
    if x == b+1:
        for x in range(dimx):
            print("-",end="")
    print() # print newline here
print("+"+"-"*dimx + ">")
```

Answer (score 0):

The last `|` is from the next line because there's no newline after `------------------`. Add a `|` with no newline before the `for` loop, and add a newline at the end.